# transform pointcloud with tf2

Tags: ros, pcl, tf2-ros, tf2, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have two tf2 frames in ROS "World" and "Robot" the world is on position 0, 0, 0 and the Robot is on different position, it is a moving robot, but for now let say he is on position 8, 4, 6.

I have a kinect v2 hooked up on ROS with the iai_bridge, so i get the pointclouds on a topic. The problem is when i lookup the transformation between the world and transform the given camera on frame "World" pointcloud to the "Robot" pointcloud the compiler gives me an error.

The code:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf2_ros/transform_listener.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/TransformStamped.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <tf2/convert.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "my_tf2_listener");

    ros::NodeHandle node;

    tf2_ros::Buffer tfBuffer;
    tf2_ros::TransformListener tfListener(tfBuffer);
    sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud_in, cloud_out;

    ros::Rate rate(10.0);
    while (node.ok()) {
        geometry_msgs::TransformStamped transformStamped;
        try {
            transformStamped = tfBuffer.lookupTransform("world", "robotarm",
                    ros::Time(0));
            std::cout << transformStamped << std::endl;
            tf2::doTransform(cloud_in, cloud_out, transformStamped);

//          pcl_ros::transformPointCloud("robotarm", cloud_in, cloud_out, tfListener);

        } catch (tf2::TransformException &ex) {
            ROS_WARN("%s", ex.what());
            ros::Duration(1.0).sleep();
            continue;
        }

        rate.sleep();
    }
    return 0;
}
;
```

My CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(learning_tf2)

add_definitions(-std=c++11)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  tf2
  tf2_ros
  tf2_msgs
  tf2_sensor_msgs
  geometry_msgs
  sensor_msgs
)


include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(turtle_tf2_listener src/turtle_tf2_listener.cpp)

target_link_libraries(turtle_tf2_listener
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

add_executable(frame_tf2_broadcaster src/frame_tf2_broadcaster.cpp)
target_link_libraries(frame_tf2_broadcaster
 ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

And the error:

```
CMakeFiles/turtle_tf2_listener.dir/src/turtle_tf2_listener.cpp.o: In function `main':
turtle_tf2_listener.cpp:(.text+0x316): undefined reference to `void tf2::doTransform<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >(sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > const&, sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >&, geometry_msgs::TransformStamped_<std::allocator<void> > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
learning_tf2/CMakeFiles/turtle_tf2_listener.dir/build.make:117: recipe for target 'learning_tf2/turtle_tf2_listener' failed
```

And finally, all the installed ros TF packages, all from the ubuntu repo's:

```
ros-kinetic-tf2
ros-kinetic-tf2-eigen
ros-kinetic-tf2-geometry-msgs
ros-kinetic-tf2-kdl
ros-kinetic-tf2-msgs
ros-kinetic-tf2-py
ros-kinetic-tf2-ros
ros-kinetic-tf2-sensor-msgs
ros-kinetic-tf2-tools
```

My question: How can I transform the pointcloud so that the pointcloud is transformed from the "World" frame to the "Robot" frame?

Best Regards,
Maurice

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262179/transform-pointcloud-with-tf2/) by [MrC11](https://answers.ros.org/users/30469/mrc11/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2017-05-20

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-05-21**:
It looks like doTransform isn't defined for PointCloud2 http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf2_geometry_msgs/html/c++/tf2__geometry__msgs_8h.html.  I was going to suggest using `pcl_ros::transformPointCloud`, but I think you'd have to use a regular tf listener rather `tf2_ros::TransformListener`.

**Comment by [MrC11](https://answers.ros.org/users/30469/mrc11/) on 2017-05-22**:
Hello, I don't get your comment. Could you please explain it a little bit better? How can I transform it in this little project?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-05-22**:
Oh I see it here http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf2/html/namespacetf2.html#a2bf447973d0079bb3fa862b3c947e147 , PointCloud2 must be a compatible type for the template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks good what you are doing and works for me!

What you actually have is a linking error. Do you link against the tf2 libraries?

So specially:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  tf2
  tf2_ros
  tf2_msgs
  tf2_sensor_msgs
  geometry_msgs
  sensor_msgs
)

 target_link_libraries(your_node_name
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

---

Update:

Can you also update your Headers so everthing is includes correctly:

```
#include <tf2_ros/buffer.h>
#include <tf2/transform_datatypes.h>
#include <tf2_sensor_msgs/tf2_sensor_msgs.h>
```

I hope I dont forget one.

---

Originally posted by [chwimmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/21005/chwimmer/) with karma: 436 on 2017-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MrC11](https://answers.ros.org/users/30469/mrc11/) on 2017-05-22**:
Hello,

it still isn't working (Edited main question).
I really don't know why it isn't working..

Best regards,
Maurice

**Comment by [chwimmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/21005/chwimmer/) on 2017-05-22**:
Its still a linking error. Can you also add `sensor_msgs` to the the catkon packages and try again?

**Comment by [chwimmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/21005/chwimmer/) on 2017-05-22**:
Ah and please always update your Question and dont post answers!

**Comment by [MrC11](https://answers.ros.org/users/30469/mrc11/) on 2017-05-22**:
I added the sensor_msgs to catkin_packages, but still the same error.

I updated the main question, you can look over there for the up-to-date CMakelists

**Comment by [MrC11](https://answers.ros.org/users/30469/mrc11/) on 2017-05-22**:
Thank you! I didn't include the right messages.

This was the one i needed:

```
#include <tf2_sensor_msgs/tf2_sensor_msgs.h>
```

Thank you very much!

**Comment by [chwimmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/21005/chwimmer/) on 2017-05-22**:
perfect!  You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've made a node (maybe later I will make it a nodelet) that uses tf2 to transform PointCloud2 messages https://github.com/lucasw/transform_point_cloud in both C++ and python, and it uses dynamic reconfigure to control what frames are used in the transform.  It can serve as an example and is useful as a standalone node to transform point clouds.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-09-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2